# How do I get netlify to use React lazy loading?

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I want to deploy a `React` app to netlify but the build fails. When I check the build logs I find that it fails where I used lazy loading to get a component.

When I use lazy loading to get a component, as shown below,

```
import React, {lazy } from 'react';

const SidebarLeft = lazy(() => import('./pages/SidebarLeft'))
```

the build fails with the error message

```
12:26:05 AM: Cannot find file './pages/WorldCases' in './src'.
```

What could be the cause of this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: are you sure is only in netlify? can you build production locally?

Comment: If it works on local production build, it should work on netlify

Comment: Yes. Local production build is working. I tried deploying on Heroku and met with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might run into this problem, it turned out that git didn't change the folder name when I did. I initially created a `Pages` folder. I later renamed it to `pages`, with a small `p`. But git didn't pick up that change. So I had to change the name back to `Pages`.